# How can I prove that this function is computable?

Tags: computer-science, computability, turing-machines

Is the following function

$$
g(x) = \begin{cases}
    1 & \text{if $\exists n \geq 0:\ \varphi_n(x) \downarrow$}\\
    \uparrow & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
$$

computable?

Please note that $\varphi_n(x) \downarrow$ means that the function with index $i$ halts on input $x$.

Answer (score 0):

**Quick loophole:**
If $\varphi_i$ means something even remotely like what it looks like it should, then your function is *the same function* as
$$ g(x) = 1 $$
which is very easy to compute.

---

(If $\varphi_i$ is something so unconventional that this doesn't work, you'll probably want to look up [dovetailing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dovetailing_%28computer_science%29). The Wikipedia article I link to is perhaps not particularly approachable, but a bit of determined googling may turn up something better.)